# Flask-Migrate Error: 'ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'alembic''

Tags: python, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

For the last few weeks I've been building a website mostly based on Miguel Grinberg's book 'Flask Web Development'. This is my 'manage.py' file for reference:

```
import os
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import User, Role, Permission, Post
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, User=User, Follow=Follow, Role=Role,
                Permission=Permission, Post=Post)

manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     manager.run()
```

And this is my app/__init.py file:

```
from flask import Flask #session, flash, url_for
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from config import config

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

mail = Mail()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy() 

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from main import main as main_blueprint
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix = '/auth')

    return app
```

As you can see it's a relatively bare-bones project, but it was going well until a few days ago when I accidentally deleted my migrations folder, which up until that point was working without perfectly fine. When I attempted to set up the migrations folder again, I got this error:

```
(website1)joshua@joshua-ThinkPad-Edge-E430 ~/website/website1 $ python manage.py db migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/home/joshua/.virtualenvs/website1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/joshua/.virtualenvs/website1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/home/joshua/.virtualenvs/website1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joshua/.virtualenvs/website1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 153, in migrate
    config = _get_config(directory, opts=['autogenerate'])
  File "/home/joshua/.virtualenvs/website1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 51, in _get_config
    config.set_main_option('script_location', directory)
  File "/home/joshua/.virtualenvs/website1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 201, in set_main_option
    self.file_config.set(self.config_ini_section, name, value)
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 753, in set
    ConfigParser.set(self, section, option, value)
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 396, in set
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'alembic'
```

I'm not really sure what to do about this, I've tried dropping then re-creating my database and running db migrate again but I got the same error as before. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling alembic but with no luck.

I'm not really sure what do do at this point, up until now whenever I've had an issue with the tutorial I took the time to figure it out on my own since I want to understand how everything works, but I'm totally stumped on this one.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py db init`?

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I consistently missed that detail, how embarassing... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy Dauros: I neglected to run python manage.py db init.